# SVG height not behaving as expected

Tags: css, svg, height, object-fit

Not that it matters but I'm using https://getwaves.io/ to generate an SVG image.

#### What should happen

The blue waves should take up much more vertical space in the gray box. It seems like it does not use `object-fit: cover`.

In fact, it should follow the size of the box, like a bounding box.

#### What I've tried to far

- Set height and width to 100%
- Set object-fit to cover
- Made sure there is a viewbox
- Made sure there are no other width and height

#### Example

It shows that an JPG image works fine but not the SVG image.

#### Question

How can I fix it?

```css
.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
}

svg, img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Just the SVG file

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
  <path fill="#0369a1" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L80,240C160,256,320,288,480,277.3C640,267,800,213,960,208C1120,203,1280,245,1360,266.7L1440,288L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z"></path>
</svg>

SVG in a box - Does not work

<div class="wrap">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path fill="#0369a1" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L80,240C160,256,320,288,480,277.3C640,267,800,213,960,208C1120,203,1280,245,1360,266.7L1440,288L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>

JPG in a box - Do work

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/96/139">
</div>
```

Comment: preserveAspectRatio="none" on the SVG ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can use the attribute `preserveAspectRatio="none"` on `<svg>`. This will stretch the SVG if you specify a height and a width.
Second you path was placed around 200 down the y axis. So, when it stretched, the transparent area above the path would also take up more space. I moved the path so that it almost hits y=0 on the top. Now the path only takes up 113 in the height and when stretched it will fill up the entire box.

I used [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) to edit the path.

```css
.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
}

svg, img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Just the SVG file

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 113">
  <path fill="#0369a1" fill-opacity="1" d="M 0 17 L 80 33 C 160 49 320 81 480 70.3 C 640 60 800 6 960 1 C 1120 -4 1280 38 1360 59.7 L 1440 81 L 1440 113 L 1360 113 C 1280 113 1120 113 960 113 C 800 113 640 113 480 113 C 320 113 160 113 80 113 L 0 113 Z"></path>
</svg>

SVG in a box - Does not work

<div class="wrap">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 113" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path fill="#0369a1" fill-opacity="1" d="M 0 17 L 80 33 C 160 49 320 81 480 70.3 C 640 60 800 6 960 1 C 1120 -4 1280 38 1360 59.7 L 1440 81 L 1440 113 L 1360 113 C 1280 113 1120 113 960 113 C 800 113 640 113 480 113 C 320 113 160 113 80 113 L 0 113 Z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>

JPG in a box - Do work

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/96/139">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer really covers everythings and more. Brilliant, thanks!